# Post PHP to MySql-db from JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have a JavaScript function (href link) that opens a modal window, and from that function/window I would like to send it to a PHP page (box.php) that has about four PHP functions; one of them is the "check_box" that checks for the other three functions. Is there a way to do that, or is it not possible/supported with the JavaScript? This is what I have:

**PHP page:**

```
<a href="javascript:openModal()" title="" style="padding-right: 10px;">LEAVE</a>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
echo $class->box->check_box() ?>
```

**JavaScript function:**

```
function openModal()
    {

        $.modal({
            content: 
                    /* This where the content of the modal window goes */

            title: 'Outside the workplace',
            width: 300,
            scrolling: false,
            actions: {
                'Close' : {
                    color: 'red',
                    click: function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
                },
                'Center' : {
                    color: 'green',
                    click: function(win) { win.centerModal(true); }
                },
                'Refresh' : {
                    color: 'blue',
                    click: function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
                },
                'Abort' : {
                    color: 'orange',
                    click: function(win) { win.closeModal(); }

                }
            },

            buttons: {
                'Close': {
                    classes:    'huge blue-gradient glossy full-width',
                    click:      function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
                                    }
                                    },


            buttonsLowPadding: true
        });
    };
```

Comment: What is data do you want to send to box.php?

Comment: Your modal doesn't do anything to try to send data, nor does it have a checkbox.  It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: The data is in the other 3 functions, where each one of them has a form. Basically, the "check_box" has the main form with buttons, once that's clicked the data is submitted to MySql-db. I just don't know how to insert the <?php echo $class->box->check_box() ?>; in the modal window. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a php page that would do the insertion. Parse the parameters from the browser in that PHP and perform an insert. Then output a message. In JavaScript show the message in designated `DIV` -- something like this (fix to your values and pass the parameters to function):

```
function setToDatabase() {
    jQuery(function($) {    
        $.ajax( {           
            url : "submittosql.php?valuetosubmit=NEWVALUE",
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data) {
                document.getElementById("YOURDIV").innerHTML=data;             
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense.